# Ansible sudo command without password checking

Tags: ansible, sudo

I would like to use ansible in a full automated context, where I cannot manually type passwords. To deal with this, I connect the servers with SSH public key, and I whitelisted severals commands such as `apt-get install *` in my `sudoers` configuration so I do not need a password to run them. For instance `sudo apt-get install git`.

However if the setting `become` is `True` in a playbook, ansible asks me for a password it does not need.

- How can I tell ansible to run a command as sudo, without asking me a password?
- Do you know another way to install apt packages without password?
- Should I use another become method?

#### sudoers conf

```
myuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install *
```

#### ansible

```
- name: install the latest version of ntpdate
  package:
    name: ntpdate
    state: latest
  become: True
```

Produces this output:

```
failed: [x.x.x.x] (item=ntpdate) => {"failed": true, "item": "python3-dev", "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

Comment: The usual way I do is to have a user who has passwordless sudo access

Comment: That is what I have done in my `sudoers` file, still, ansible asks me for a password.

Comment: ok. Are you able to ssh to target host using that user without specifying the password ?

Comment: is there any solution for that so far?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you cannot do it without enabling all commands (or at least `python`).

Ansible does not run the commands as you expect it to run. It runs Python scripts. You can see the exact command when you execute `ansible-playbook` with `-vvv`. They are much more complex and to enable them you would have to add them to `sudoers`, for example:

```
sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-xxxxxx;
  /usr/bin/python /var/www/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxx/apt.py;
  rm -rf "/var/www/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxx/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'
  && sleep 0
```

The tricky part is that all spaces, quotes, and other special characters are relevant and until you get the correct command pattern by trial and error, replacing characters with wildcards, the system will not allow the command to run with elevated privileges. Effectively you won't be able to whitelist all the commands Ansible runs.

The only exception is `raw` module which runs the given command intact.

Comment: I can live with that by adding the very command ansible uses to the sudoers exception. However the problem is that ansible checks for a password before running any sudo command, whatever the command is: `sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-xxxxxx; /usr/bin/python /var/www/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxx/apt.py; rm -rf "/var/www/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxx/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"' && sleep 0`

Comment: Also I would like to avoid using `raw` since the very purpose of ansible is to automate everything :)

Comment: No it doesn't ask, but it complains it has no root password, and quits. See the ansible output in the main question.

Comment: @azmeuk Because you did not add the exact command which Ansible tries to run. Try using wildcards instead of spaces, quotes, etc. What you put in `sudoers` is sensitive to all of that. And that's what i meant by writing it's effectively impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In all the Ansible playbooks I have worked on, I had to do only 2 things so that tasks run with become:True

1. Create file `/etc/sudoers.d/demo` on the target hosts with below content:

   demo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
2. Copy ssh id from Ansible host to target host using `ssh-copy-id`

Answer (score 1):

template/without_sudo

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown
```

tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Sudoers no password
  raw: echo '{{ user_password }}' | sudo -S sh -c 'echo "{{ lookup('file', 'templates/without_sudo') }}" > /etc/sudoers.d/without_sudo'
```

no sudo for the rest of the ansible command

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ansible 'command' module with sudo as part of the command, instead of 'become: yes'

```
- name: install the latest version of ntpdate
  command: 'sudo apt-get update ntpdate'
```

The downside is that this is much less portable.  The upside is, it works... and you only need to whitelist the specific command.

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion, if you set your node with =(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL. then anybody: including the hackers can access your nodes.

so what I can suggest ,

```
ansible-playbook <name>.yml --ask-sudo-pass
```

this will ask your node sudo password. and u can execute ur operation, as I guess you know ur node's credential.